# Prove that $1000...00001$ cannot be a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am using the fact that a perfect square plus $1$ is not divisible by 3. So, what I got was $$(10n+1)^2+1=100n^2+20n+2=2(50n^2+10n)+2$$ Where $k=50n^2+10n$, giving the form $2k+2$ which is not divisible by $3$.

Is this a good enough explanation for the fact that $10n+1$ cannot be a perfect square?

Edit: It should have the form of $1000...00001$

Comment: It's not true. $11^2=121=(12*10+1)$.

Comment: $2k+2$ is often divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a perfect square because

$$\begin{align}10^n+1&\equiv 1^n+1\pmod{3} \\
&\equiv 2\pmod{3}
\end{align}$$ but no square is $2\pmod{3}$.